# I can't do something in a docker container with Oracle

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I'm running docker container in docker-compose.yalm

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  builder-materials-market:
    image: 'container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest'
    container_name: ${DOCKER_CONTAINER_NAME}
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      ORACLE_SID: ${ORACLE_SID}
      ORACLE_PWD: ${ORACLE_PWD}
      ORACLE_PDB: ${ORACLE_PDB}
      ORACLE_EDITION: ${ORACLE_EDITION}
    ports:
      - '${ORACLE_PORT}:1521'
    volumes:
      - 'oracle-data:/opt/oracle/oracle-data'
      - 'oracle-backup:/opt/oracle/backup'
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          'CMD',
          'sqlplus',
          '-L',
          'sys/Oracle_123@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB as sysdba',
          '@healthcheck.sql',
        ]
      interval: '30s'
      timeout: '10s'
      retries: 5
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536

volumes:
  oracle-data:
  oracle-backup:
```

Then I go into the container via `sqlplus / as sysdba` and try to change the PDB via `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=my_pdb;`.

It is noteworthy that it worked for me today, but I had to restart it and after that, after every attempt to do something, the error `ORA-01034 ORACLE not available` flies out.

I tried to make a `startup`command based on the answers in different sources, but then I got the error:

```sql
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/dbs/init.ora'
```

I tried to restart the container, Docker itself, increase the allocated memory, but to no avail.

It is noteworthy that everything runs fine on my home laptop on archlinux, but when I try to run on a working laptop that is on windows, everything is to no avail, although it worked and ran perfectly for several weeks.